Prove that spectral decomposition is the minimal ensemble decomposition
I understand that the spectral decomposition of a density matrix
$\rho$ expresses it in terms of its eigenvalues and eigenvectors:
$$\rho=\sum_i\lambda_i\left|\psi_i\middle\rangle\!\middle\langle\psi\right|\,,$$
where $\lambda_i$ are the eigenvalues ($\lambda_i\geqslant0$ and $\sum_i\lambda_i=1$) and $\left|\psi_i\right\rangle$ are the corresponding orthonormal eigenvectors.
It is often stated that the spectral decomposition represents the minimal ensemble decomposition of $\rho$, in the sense that the number of terms in this decomposition (the rank of $\rho$) is the smallest possible among all valid decompositions of $\rho$ into a probabilistic mixture of pure states:
$$\rho=\sum_kp_k\left|\varphi_k\middle\rangle\!\middle\langle\varphi_k\right|\,,$$ where $p_k>0$, $\sum_kp_k=1$, and $\left|\varphi_k\right\rangle$ are not necessarily orthogonal.
I am looking for mathematical intuition and a deeper understanding of why the spectral decomposition is minimal in this sense. Specifically:

Uniqueness: Why is the number of terms in the spectral decomposition exactly the rank of $\rho$, and how is this related to the linear independence of eigenvectors?

Optimality: Is there a formal proof or geometric explanation that shows no ensemble decomposition of $\rho$ can involve fewer pure states than its spectral decomposition?

Applications: How does this minimality play a role in practical quantum information tasks, such as entanglement characterization or state preparation?


I’d appreciate any mathematical insights, geometric interpretations, or references that clarify this concept!

Let's take your decomposition
$$
\rho=\sum_kp_k|\varphi_k\rangle\langle\varphi_k|
$$
and assume that the number of $k$ is smaller than the rank of $\rho$. Now, consider the space $S$ spanned by all the $\{|\varphi_k\rangle\}$. Any state $|\gamma\rangle$ that is orthogonal to this span has 0 support on $\rho$: $\rho|\gamma\rangle=0$, and is therefore an eigenvector with eigenvalue 0.
Now, given that the number of $k$ is smaller than the rank of $\rho$, there exists a state in the span of the eigenvectors of $\rho$ which is orthogonal $S$. By definition, its expectation is non=zero, in contradiction with the previous statement. It is therefore impossible to find a set of states that is smaller than the rank of the matrix.
